# Remaining limits of an API using express-rate-limit framework in Node js

Tags: node.js, rest, express, rate-limiting

I am creating an api where I want to limit the number of calls to the api. I am using Express-rate-limit framework to create the limit.
But I also want to show the number of requests the user has.

P.S. Im new to Node.js

```
    const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

const rateLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 1 * 60 * 1000, 
  max: 5,
  statusCode : 403,
  message: 'You have exceeded the 5 requests in 1 min limit!',
  headers: true,
});


router.get("/call_api", checkauth,rateLimiter, async function(req,res,next)  {


    await fetch("http://localhost:8000/get_number", {
        method : "GET",
        // headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    })
    .then((response) => response.json()).then((response1) => {
        res.status(200).json({
            number : response1.number
        });
    })

    // res.status(200).json({
    //     message : "Generating a random number"
    // })
  });

router.get("/remaining_limit",checkauth,rateLimiter, (req,res) => {
      res.status(500).json({
          remaining_limits : "You have _ remaining limits" //the number of remaining limits
      });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs reference a [Request API](https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit#request-api)

> A `req.rateLimit` property is added to all requests with the `limit`, `current`, and `remaining` number of requests and, if the store provides it, a `resetTime` Date object. These may be used in your application code to take additional actions or inform the user of their status.

Your `/remaining_limit` endpoint could be like so:

```js
router.get("/remaining_limit",checkauth,rateLimiter, (req,res) => {
  const remaining = req.rateLimit.remaining;
  res.status(200).json({ 
  // Note that we return 200 OK because the endpoint is working as it should - returning a value
  remaining_limits : `You have ${remaining} remaining limits` // using a template literal
});
```